# Will below code of logging will mess the log file?

Tags: python, logging, flask, uwsgi

Below are some very simple flask code. I write a http api which will return 'hello' and **log the string 'hello'  into /tmp/mylog.log**  if you send request to http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello

I have been told if multiple processes write log into one file will have problems. Because there is no process level lock on the file. So the content of log might be messed.

But if I run below flask code in uwsgi there will be multiple workeres. So  multiple processes. Then I think there will be problems.

But I did not find any problems while testing. 
So why there is no problem? AND should it have problems?

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# The only important thing here is to specify the log file /tmp/mylog.log

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='/tmp/mylog.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(filename)s[line:%(lineno)d] %(levelname)s %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    logger.info('hello')
    return 'hello'
```

Comment: Don't open the logger directly from Flask, *leave logging to the WSGI server*. If your WSGI server is configured to use multiple processes to handle requests, you now *will* try to write to the same file from multiple workers. A good WSGI server will handle Python's logging configuration for you and gather logs from multiple child processes in a single file controlled from the main configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Flask doesn't do anything. The default for Python logging is to output to `sys.stdout`. When using something like uWSGI or Gunicorn, they will collect each worker's stdout into the log file you configure. Or you can configure Python's logging system to output where and how you want, although this will be much less straightforward. In general, it's simplest to let the WSGI server collect and output stdout from the workers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.logger` to log things in Flask. It will work even when multiple Flask processes are running.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/'):
def index():
   app.logger.info("Hit the main route !")
   return render_template('index.html')
```

If you'd like to customize the log messages, you can also use Python's `logging` library, and it's infinitely customizable logs.

Just add the following at the top of your files:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and, to log messages:

```
log.debug("complex mathematical equations and heavy outputs")
log.info("the sky is blue")
log.error("something's not right")
log.critical("dangeeeer ! its's blowing up !")
```

You can Google the many tutorials online to do logging (like setting up file handlers, formatters, loggers, ...) with Python.

Comment: sorry I did not ask clearly. can you check my question  again?

Comment: you won't have any problem, either method you choose, with writing to the same log file under multiprocesses condition. Running Flask in production for 2 years, and none of that ever occured, and I'm using both methods, and gunicorn or wsgi as webservers.